# DBunit org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, dbunit

I'm using dbunit, my class is giving an error message. Can someone help me. I am using PostgreSQL database.
Thank you.

```
public class ConexaoDb {
    final private String url = "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.77:5432/caixa5";  
       final private String usuario = "postgres";  
       final private String senha = "murah";  
       final private String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";  
       Connection con;  

    public Connection getConnection() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {  
         try {  
           Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

         } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {  
      //     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "não encontrado");  
           System.out.println("Driver não encontrado!!");  
           cnfe.printStackTrace();  
         }  
         try {  
           con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, senha);  
           //Conseguiu conectar...  
           IDatabaseConnection connection = new DatabaseConnection(con);
           DatabaseConfig dbConfig = connection.getConfig();
           dbConfig.setProperty(DatabaseConfig.PROPERTY_DATATYPE_FACTORY, new PostgresqlDataTypeFactory());




         } catch (SQLException se) {  
           System.out.println("Não foi possivel conectar, talvex o URL, usuario ou senha errada");  
           se.printStackTrace();  
         } catch (DatabaseUnitException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
         return con;  
       }  
}
```

Error:

```
[main] WARN org.dbunit.dataset.AbstractTableMetaData - Potential problem<br> found: The configured data type factory<br> 
'class org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.DefaultDataTypeFactory' might cause<br> problems with the current database 'PostgreSQL'<br> 
(e.g. some datatypes may not be supported properly). In rare cases you might<br> see this message because the list of supported<br> 
database products is incomplete (list=[derby]). If so please request a<br> java-class update via the forums.If you are using your<br> 
own IDataTypeFactory extending DefaultDataTypeFactory, ensure that you<br> override getValidDbProducts() to specify the supported database products.<br>

java.lang.NullPointerException<br>
    at banco_dados.TesteBanco.validarDados(TesteBanco.java:61)<br>
    at banco_dados.TesteBanco.main(TesteBanco.java:95)<br>
```